# DSE Cassandra OperationTimedOutException

Tags: cassandra, mapreduce, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have a table with very huge data in cassandra. I am trying to read the data on partition using dse driver through hadoop mapreduce program. For some partition there might be more than 100 Million rows in the partition and when I am trying to read these partitions I am getting OperationTimedOutException.

Below is the stack trace -

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X:XXXX] Timed out waiting for server response
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException.copy(OperationTimedOutException.java:17)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:28)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:304)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:260)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:134)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet.all(ArrayBackedResultSet.java:123)
```

I have tried below things and it didn't work out for me-

1. setFetchSize() to large number like 250000.
2. setReadTimeoutMillis() to 30 seconds

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems Cassandra is not able to fulfil request within specified time. You can increase below parameter in cassandra.yaml file to deal with timeouts to an extent only not much higher.

`read_request_timeout_in_ms:
write_request_timeout_in_ms:`

If it doesn't help then you should look into your cassandra's log for other anomalies like tombstone etc..

Comment: GC_GRACE_SECONDS is set to zero so there won't be any tombstones created.

Comment: @Charitrakocheri, unless you fancy having zombie data in your cluster, I would highly recommend that you revert that...

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra configuration file got parameter to limit the response time. If the response takes more time, you are bound to get `Timed out waiting for server response`. But this can be configured manually in cassandra.yaml file.

Please change the below parameters as per need :

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
```

In case you if you don't have access to cassandra configuration file. Use Pagination feature of cassandra to Query large results or you can handle pagination in your code itself.

Comment: I dont have access to cassandra.yaml file so I changed this settings in mapreduce code using driver methods setReadTimeoutMillis().

Comment: Driver cannot overrule Cassandra configuration. If you are looking for high number of results, use pagination feature of Cassandra  or write a code that can help in pagination of results.